# change images size of all images - linux terminal

Tags: linux

Say I wanted to change the size of a picture and keep the name the same, in terminal I would type: `convert picture1.jpg -resize 1280x720! picture1.jpg` Now what if I had a folder with hundred of these pictures and I wanted to change them all to 1280x720 and keep the same name. Is there any easier way then typing out that line for each picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd myfolder
for file in *.jpg
do
    convert "$file" -resize 1280x720! "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In case there is tons of images you might run into trouble using an `for f in *.jpg` approach. In this case you might want to do something like:

```
find myfolder -maxdepth 1 -name *.jpg -exec convert \{\} -resize 1280x720! \{\} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what `mogrify` is for:

```
mogrify -resize 1280x720! *.jpg
```